# PHP: strtotime() and time() shows different timestamp

Tags: php

```
echo strtotime('2017-05-03 16:16:01');
echo "<br>";
echo time();
```

I ran this query at 2017-05-03 16:28:01 so output of time() should be higher and strtotime('2017-05-03 16:16:01'); should be lower but I am not getting the output.

above code prints

```
1493828161
1493809172 //
```

But I expected it to print if I run the query at 2017-05-03 16:02:01 same timestamp

```
1493809172
1493809172
```

But it prints with big difference.

Comment: [time](http://php.net/time) : Return **current** Unix timestamp

Comment: Of course they are different. `time()` is the current time, which is May 3rd. Your `strtotime()` is May 1st.

Comment: First output is okay, because `strtotime('2017-05-01 16:02:01');` this will print the timestamp of that moment and `time` output current timestamp

Comment: @Qirel i updated my question I am trying for today timestamp.. strtotime('2017-05-03 16:02:01');

Comment: @hassan so the output of time() should be higher than  strtotime('2017-05-03 16:02:01'); if I am running this query in my system at 2017-05-03 16:28:01

Comment: that's because you are converting time in the future ! , `2017-05-03 16:16:01`

Answer (score 0):

`time()` return dynamic current timestamp which will change every moment.

Where as your passed date is static date, which will convert it into its `timestamp()` value and will show it.

Conclusion : time() is that which can not be stopped, it run as time pass by whereas timestamp with given date time, it will always show static value timestamp of given date time.

Answer (score 0):

strtotime('2017-05-01 16:02:01')

1. Convert provided time into string to time

time ()

1. That convert to Returns the current time as a Unix timestamp